# Blender Eevee crashes on scene render .. What are typical causes?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Some Tests Performed on Scene[1]
Scene[1] contains 3 major meshes

- Eevee fails immediately ... one second or less.
  Using Render Layers to reduce complexity of scene, did not produce better results yet. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/render/layers/introduction.html#bpy-types-viewlayer-name
- Workbench render succeeds in limited testing.
- Cycles render works in limited testing.

Windows GPU graph from task manager spikes on eevee crash.

The Eevee  scene render worked in the past.
Scene stats
Verts 80,000 Face 78,000 Tris 152,000 Objects 52
Memory 70M, VRAM 0.4/6GB

Scene[2] was created with reduced meshes to investigate problem .. Eevee in all following cases

- Eevee A single cube both [failed] and rendered successfully on multiple tests
- With a single mesh copied from Scene[1] Eevee was successful.  Single light included.
- Another mesh pasted from Scene[1] successful
- Another light added .. failed

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Blender was crashing for me when I was rendering and after a bit of testing I found out that if you have an incorrect color profile embedded in your jpegs or pngs that it crashes EEVEE. It might not be the same problem you're having though.

To fix this open your files in photoshop and make sure when you *Export as* <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> that you have both *Convert to sRGB* and *Embed color profile* checked.

If you only have embed color profile, Blender gave me errors and crashed every time.

It sounds like your issue might be a bit different but its pretty similar so I thought I'd post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official [`Blender documentation`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/crash.html) on crashes:

> ## Crashes
>
> The most common causes of Blender crashes:
>
> - Running out of memory.
> - Issues with graphics hardware or drivers.
> - Bugs in Blender.
>
> Firstly, you may be able to recover your work with *File ‣ Recover ‣
> Auto Save…*.
>
> To prevent the problem from happening again, you can check that the
> graphics drivers are up to date ([Graphics Hardware](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/gpu/index.html#troubleshooting-gpu-index)), upgrade your
> machine’s hardware (the RAM or graphics card), and disable some
> options that are more memory intensive:
>
> - Reduce undo steps *Preferences ‣ System ‣ Memory & Limits ‣ Undo Steps*.
> - Using multisample anti-aliasing also increases the memory usage and
>   makes the display slower.
> - On Linux, the Window Manager (KDE and Gnome for example) may be using
>   hardware accelerated effects (e.g. window shadows and transparency)
>   that are using up the memory that Blender needs. Try disabling the
>   desktop effects or switch to a lightweight Window Manager.
>
> To check memory usage by Blender:
>
> - On Windows, use Task Manager and sort by Memory.
> - On macOS, use Activity Monitor.app and open Memory tab. Alternatively,
>   run `top -o MEM`.
> - On Linux, run `top -o %MEM`.
>
> ## Crash Log
>
> When Blender crashes, it writes out a text file which
> contains information that may help identify the cause of the crash.
> Usually, this file is written in the Temporary Directory directory.
>
> This file contains a log of tools used up until the crash as well as
> some other debug information. When reporting bugs about crashes it can
> be helpful to attach this file to your reports, especially when others
> are unable to reproduce the crash.
>
> **Windows**
>
> On a crash, a file is written based on the name of the
> currently loaded blend-file, so test.blend will create a file called
> `test.crash.txt`.
>
> Batch scripts are provided in Blender installation directory which may
> be run to obtain the Blender debug log and system info text files:
>
> `blender_debug_log.cmd` is used in most cases.
>
> `blender_debug_gpu.cmd` and `blender_debug_gpu_workaround.cmd` log
> GPU-related errors.
>
> `blender_factory_startup.cmd` starts Blender with default settings which
> is recommended for debugging.
>
> If the crash happens in Blender module, stack trace is also written to
> a file named `blender.crash.txt`. The path to that file can be found at
> the end of `blender_debug_log.txt` file.
>
> **MacOS**
>
> After crash, macOS Crash Reporter shows a window with backtrace
> after some time, or when Blender is opened again. Copy the text in the
> crash report and save it in a text file. That file should be attached
> to the bug report while following other bug reporting guidelines.
>
> Some `.crash` files can also be found in
> `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/` with the name of format:
> `Blender_YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS_MACNAME.crash`. If a report is present
> corresponding to the time of crash, that file can also provide hints
> about cause of the crash. Alternatively, Console.app can be used to
> navigate all “User Reports” (see sidebar in the app).
>
> **Linux**
>
> On a crash, a file named `blender.crash.txt` is written in `/tmp`
> directory.
>
> > **Note**
> >
> > More logs can be obtained by running Blender from Command Line and
> > using:
> > `--factory-startup --debug-all flags`
> > See [Launching from the Command Line and Command Line Arguments](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/launch/index.html#command-line-launch-index).